# Category theory: How to prove $X \times (Y + Z) \cong (X \times Y) + (X \times Z)$?

Tags: proof-writing, category-theory

I was trying to prove the isomorphisms on page 16 [https://homepages.cwi.nl/~janr/papers/files-of-papers/2011_Jacobs_Rutten_new.pdf](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Ejanr/papers/files-of-papers/2011_Jacobs_Rutten_new.pdf).
I got stuck on proving the last isomorphism:

$$X \times (Y + Z) \cong (X \times Y) + (X \times Z)$$

I tried to construct two morphisms $x$ and $x^{-1}$ such that $x \circ x^{-1} = id $ and $x^{-1} \circ x = id$ using the universal properties of the product and coproduct.

I am struggling to get $x^{-1}$ from $X \times (Y + Z)$ to $ (X \times Y) + (X \times Z)$. I already found $x$ as seen in the following sketch:
[Obtaining x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbB3S.jpg)

I was trying to use the universal property of the coproduct $Y + Z$ to construct a morphism (called $j$) to $(X \times Y) + (X \times Z)$. Then I could use $ j \circ p_2 = x^{-1}$. Here is my attempt in another sketch:

[Attemping to get x^-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn0Dm.jpg)

I am glad for any help.

Edit: It is not true in general (but for example in the category SET).

Comment: What are your hypotheses? This isn't true in general.

Comment: Your construction of the morphism $x:(X\times Y)+(X\times Z)\to X\times (Y+Z)$ is correct, but in general it is not an isomorphism; it is true for the category of sets, but you will need to use properties of this category to prove it.

Comment: Probably I misunderstood the paper. I thought it was true in general.
Can someone give me a hint in which category this is not true, so I can work out a counterexample?

Comment: For example, in **Grp**, $C_2\times (C_3+C_5)$ has non-trivial center, but $(C_2\times C_3)+(C_2\times C_3)$ has trivial center

Comment: Thanks to everyone. If a proof in general is not possible that is a sufficient answer for me. Maybe I will have a look at the category of groups sometime in the future.

Comment: If your category is cartesian-closed, then it will be distributive, because left adjoints (in this case products) preserve colimits (in this case coproducts). This holds in the category of sets, for instance.

Comment: In groups $G\times(0+0)=G$ while $G\times 0 + G\times 0=G+G$